# antd form item validation fails if default value haven't been changed

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have following `antd` form in my React component. Default value comes from props, I'm about to change redux store on submit. But if user doesn't change input value and pushes 'Save', validation fails and in console log i got 
`util.js:19 async-validator: ["'title' is required"]`

```
<Form name="title" onFinish={this.submitEdit} >
    <Form.Item name="title" rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Required field' }]}>
        <Input defaultValue={this.props.title} placeholder="Enter entry title"/>
    </Form.Item>
    <div>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">Save</Button>
        <Button onClick={this.cancelEdit}>Cancel</Button>
    </div>
</Form>
```

I hade similar issue with antd calendar control. Tried to write custom validator, but it looks like if nothng had changed, input value is undefined. Do I have any chance to make it work?

Answer (score 8):

Yes according to the doc [here](https://ant.design/components/form/#Form.Item) you need to use the `initialValue` prop on `<Form.Item>` and then it works.

```
<Form name="title" onFinish={this.submitEdit} >
    <Form.Item
      name="title"
      rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Required field' }]} 
      initialValue={this.props.title}
      >
        <Input placeholder="Enter entry title"/>
    </Form.Item>
    <div>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">Save</Button>
        <Button onClick={this.cancelEdit}>Cancel</Button>
    </div>
</Form>
```

Cheers.